# How do I reset an angular control's value back to its binding?

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I have a control that is binded to data.

```html
<input [value]="myData">
```

This is one way binding. Lets say I type something in the input. `myData` will not change. How do I reset the control value back to `myData`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do it in code:

1. Set `myData` to a different value (e.g. an empty string)
2. Call `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges`
3. Set `myData` back to it original value

```
public myData = "Hello world!";

constructor(private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

private refreshInputDisplay(): void {
    const oldData = this.myData;
    this.myData = "";
    this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
    this.myData = oldData;
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivmsuq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) for a demo.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `ViewChild` and set its value accordingly:

**HTML**

```html
<input [value]="myData" #oneWayInput />
```

**Component TS**

```ts
// A property in your component
@ViewChild('oneWayInput') oneWayInput: ElementRef;

// When you want to revert the value in the input
this.oneWayInput.nativeElement.value = this.myData;
```

Or you could use two-way binding, capture the initial value in a separate variable, then set the bound value to the initial value whenever you want:

```ts
initialValue: string;
myData: string;

// Where you set myData
this.initialValue = this.myData;

// Reset value
this.myData = this.initialValue;
```